# Class binding based on status of objects nested in v-for loops

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-deployment

i have an issue correctly displaying the status of my nested objects.

The Structure is as follows.

A -> B -> C

A contains a List of B's and B contains a List of C's.

So there are usually 2+ Bs with 2+ Cs each.

The entire structure is basically a tree.

This is a very simplified version of what i am trying to do:

```
<div v-for="a in As">
  <i v-if="a?.showWarning" class="fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger"/>
  <div v-for="b in a.Bs">
     <i v-if="b?.showWarning" class="fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger"/>
     <div v-for="c in b.Cs">
        <i v-if="c?.showWarning" class="fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger"/>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A, B and C each have a .showWarning that is either an true or false.
I want to display a warning symbol on each Component that has an error.
Sa there could be an error onToplevel (A), or further down the structure (B,C).

I tried using v-if="c?.showWarning" on my -tags showing the symbol.

This works initially, but a change to c.status will NOT re-evaluate the v-if tags so the warning symbol will not vanish once the user corrects the error.

I tried using a computed method as suggested but the problem is that i need a parameter else i wont know where in the structure i am so i cannot really find out using the data() ...

I can just create a method with a parameter and use it in the v-bind:class="evalueateError(object)" but that will also not update on change of the corresponding property.

I can add :key="object?.showWarning" but that will re-render the entire component when the property changes ....

I could just use vue.js to set costum ids on the html objects and do it myself in javascript but i rather use vue.js for this.

But i ran out of options here what is the correct way to do this???
I want to color-code and display error symbols in my hierarchy depending on the state of the corresponding object in my hierarchy.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Oliver

Comment: Are you running into the reactivity caveat when changing `c`?  You may have to use [`this.$set` or `Vue.set`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).  Showing that code would help to confirm

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer.


reactivity is working fine also in the b and c level.

whats not working is evaluating the class bindings on updates.

it only works if i use computed methods for this.

but then its impossible to pass any argument.

and without any argument to the function doing the formatting i cannot tell where in my structure i am.

it works perfectly on A level since there is only one A and my formatting function needs no argument. 
But when i want to format a B or C depending on its internal state i am doomed.
I found no way to do this =(

Comment: update: also my structure is not changing since it is predefined, so no new B or C are created. Only values already present from the start change ( the status ).

I was under the impression that Vue.set is only needed if i change the structure of my object?